# Subset function in R is not subsetting the way I want it to

Tags: r

I am trying to subset my dataset on the basis of species RPKM value and dnds value, such that for each specie the RPKM value can range from 0 to 170, and dnds value can range from 0.10 to 0.40. I've used the subset functions as shown below. At first I tried adding these dimensions in one subset function but it wasn't working. Then I broke it down (as shown below). It seems to work for RPKM but I am still getting dNdS values greater than 0.40. 
Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here.

This is my code:

```
subset_data <- subset(mammals, mammals$RPKM <= 170)

subset_data2 <- subset(subset_data,mammals$RPKM >= 0)

subset_data3 <- subset(subset_data2,mammals$dNdS >= 0.10)

subset_data4 <- subset(subset_data3,mammals$dNdS <= 0.40)
```

Comment: Yeah I've checked that too. Its numeric. What are you suggesting?

Comment: I suggested that in case it is not numeric, it can be a problem

Comment: Try doing it in one line without `subset`, e.g., `subset_data <- mammals[mammals$RPKM <= 170 & mammals$RPKM >= 0 & mammals$dNdS >= 0.10 & mammals$dNdS <= 0.40,]`

Comment: Oh, just noticed your code, you are subsetting on the `subset_data` with the condition from the original dataset i.e. `subset(subset_data,mammals$RPKM >= 0)` would be `subset(subset_data, RPKM >= 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Run

```
str(mammals)
```

example

```
> str(iris)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Check the variable RPKM & dNdS types.  They should be "num" or "int".

2) Use ?base::Logic

example

```
> subset(iris, Sepal.Length>6&Sepal.Width<3&Petal.Length<5&Petal.Width<1.4)
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
59          6.6         2.9          4.6         1.3 versicolor
72          6.1         2.8          4.0         1.3 versicolor
74          6.1         2.8          4.7         1.2 versicolor
75          6.4         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor
88          6.3         2.3          4.4         1.3 versicolor
98          6.2         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor
```

In your case

```
subset(mammals, mammals$RPKM <= 170 & mammals$RPKM >= 0 & mammals$dNdS >= 0.1 & mammals$dNdS <= 0dNdS.4)
```